# phone value not importing from etc/config.xml

Tags: magento2, configuration

I have the following Magento Store Configuration set in my modules **etc/config.xml** file.

*app/code/NameSpace/MyModule/etc/config.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
    <general>
        <country>
            <default>GB</default>
        </country>
        <locale>
            <code>en_GB</code>
            <timezone>Europe/London</timezone>
            <weight_unit>kgs</weight_unit>
        </locale>
        <store_information>
            <phone>7771234</phone>
        </store_information>
    </general>
</default>
```

It's all working, except for `general/store_information/phone`.

Any idea what is wrong with it.

I have cleared the cache, and ran `setup:upgrade` and `app:config:import`.

Comment: can i see your syste.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
            <system>
                <section id="store_information" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" 
        showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <field id="phone" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" 
        showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">                                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                        </field>
                     </group>   
                </section>
            </system>
        </config>
```

Please check

```
<store_information> group id
            <phone>7771234</phone>field id
        </store_information>
```

Comment: Is you system xml like this for phone?